# Transmission disengages itself

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, accord

Seems like my car disengage itself from drive to neutral while in motion. I drive a 2004 Honda Accord. When in drive and in motion, the car starts slowing down even with my foot on accelerator.  It seems like it shifts  into neutral itself. After about 10 seconds it seems to reconnect and starts moving again.

Please, what is the explanation for these symptoms?

Comment: When was the last time you had the trans serviced (fluid change)? Probably is low on fluid, get it serviced right away.

Answer (score 1):

These Honda transmissions are prone to failure. Which is unfortunate. I have the same car and the transmission failed at about 130,000 miles.

You can check the transmission fluid. With the engine off and the car on a level surface remove the transmission dipstick, clean and put it back in and then pull it out. Now you should see the level at the upper mark. The fluid color should be that of red tinted tea. This fluid is a not a generic type, it is particular to Honda. If the fluid is full and not to dirty the failure is most likely a failure of one or more of the clutches. This would require the unit be removed and repaired.

Your symptoms suggest that a clutch has failed and that the material from that clutch is filling the filter thus blocking oil supply to rest of the transmission.